# Downloading file/files in Java. Multithreading, this works?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, oop, jframe

First, everyone needs to know i'm relatively new to Java coding. To be more precise i'm completely new to Object Oriented Programming.

---

### To the question.

I am trying to create a download class that updates a progress bar it was given to show its progress. And possibly anything else I decide to give it in the future to update.

The issue currently is that, in my head, this shouldn't work. I can do anything i want on the "main" method and the GUI is still responsive and quick. In my experience in past programming, this is not possible unless i thread the GUI. Why is this?

Since it works, is this ok to do it this way?

---

Class Main

```
package atomicElectronics;

import java.io.IOException;

import atomicElectronics.physical.AtomFrame;
import atomicElectronics.utility.Download;

public class Initial {

    static AtomFrame atomLauncher;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        atomLauncher = new AtomFrame();
        atomLauncher.start();

        System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        Download theDownload = new Download();
        theDownload.fileProgressBar(atomLauncher.progressBar);
        try {
            theDownload.exicute("http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/last/win64/vlc-2.1.3-win64.exe", "C:\\Users\\TrinaryAtom\\AppData\\Roaming");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // TODO Add Download Methods
        // theDownload.updateBarTotal(JProgressBar);
        // theDownload.updateLabelSpeed(String);
        // theDownload.updateLabelTotal(String);
        // theDownload.addFile(File);
        // theDownload.addFiles(Files);
    }

}
```

---

Class AtomFrame

```
package atomicElectronics.physical;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;

public class AtomFrame extends JFrame{

    public JProgressBar progressBar;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4010489530693307355L;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        AtomFrame testFrame = new AtomFrame();
        testFrame.start();
    }

    public AtomFrame(){
        initializeComponents();
    }

    public void initializeComponents(){
        this.setSize(400, 400);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("Atom Launcher");
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 5));

        progressBar = new JProgressBar();
        this.add(progressBar);

        //this.pack();
    }

    public void start() {
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void close() {
        this.dispose();
    }
}
```

---

Class Download

```
package atomicElectronics.utility;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.JProgressBar;

public class Download {

    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;
    private JProgressBar fileProgressBar;

    public Download() {
    }

    public void fileProgressBar(JProgressBar fileBar) {
        fileProgressBar = fileBar;
    }

    public void exicute(String fileURL, String saveDir) throws IOException  {

        URL url = new URL(fileURL);
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        int responseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();

        // always check HTTP response code first
        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            String fileName = "";
            String disposition = httpConn.getHeaderField("Content-Disposition");
            String contentType = httpConn.getContentType();
            double contentLength = httpConn.getContentLength();

            if (disposition != null) {
                // extracts file name from header field
                int index = disposition.indexOf("filename=");
                if (index > 0) {


          fileName = disposition.substring(index + 9,
                        disposition.length());
            }
        } else {
            // extracts file name from URL
            fileName = fileURL.substring(fileURL.lastIndexOf("/") + 1,
                    fileURL.length());
        }

        System.out.println("Content-Type = " + contentType);
        System.out.println("Content-Disposition = " + disposition);
        System.out.println("Content-Length = " + contentLength);
        System.out.println("fileName = " + fileName);

        // opens input stream from the HTTP connection
        InputStream inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
        String saveFilePath = saveDir + File.separator + fileName;

        // opens an output stream to save into file
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(saveFilePath);

        double totalRead = 0;
        int bytesRead = -1;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            totalRead += bytesRead;
            System.out.println((totalRead / contentLength) * 100);
            fileProgressBar.setValue((int)((totalRead / contentLength) * 100));
        }

        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();

        System.out.println("File downloaded");
    } else {
        System.out.println("No file to download. Server replied HTTP code: " + responseCode);
    }
    httpConn.disconnect();

}
```

}

Comment: `I am trying to create a download class that updates a progress bar it was given to show its progress` First mistake, mixing logic and presentation. Make a different class for each task (Single responsability principle) and connect them through an "open" interface (v.g. the Observer pattern)

Comment: It works because the main method is not being run on the Swing event thread, so you have more than one thread running even though you didn't explicitly set this up.

Comment: The download class could receive the progress bar object. In the future it wont be required. I am going to make the download class work  without the need for GUI, then, make the GUI methods dynamic. Connecting them through an open interface, although off topic, is confusing and unfamiliar. Do you have an example that reflects what it looks like in my example.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Awesome, That is a VERY useful feature of this.

Comment: But you don't want to do it this way as it is very brittle. Use a SwingWorker -- do it correctly so as not to mess up later when you appropriately take most of this code out of the main method.

Comment: Ok, right on, so i need to learn how to use SwingWorker. Got any examples or education material i can use to learn it?

Comment: Google "Concurrency in Swing" and read the first hit article.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels leave an answer of this and i'll mark it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggestions:

- Use a SwingWorker to do your background thread work.
- Inside your SwingWorker, set its progress "bound" property via `setProgress(int progress)`. The value should be between 1 and 100.
- Don't have your SwingWorker/file downloader hold the JProgressBar or any Swing components.
- Add a PropertyChangeListener to your SwingWorker and monitor changes in the progress property.
- Never make your Swing fields (or most and and all fields) public. Limit access, and instead change object state via methods.
- Read the tutorial [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for the necessary details.

For example, the code below is a gross simplification and downloads no files, but should give you the idea:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Initial {

   static AtomFrame atomLauncher;

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      atomLauncher = new AtomFrame();
      atomLauncher.start();

      System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

      final Download theDownload = new Download();
      theDownload.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {

         @Override
         public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent pcEvt) {
            if ("progress".equals(pcEvt.getPropertyName())) {
               int progress = theDownload.getProgress();
               atomLauncher.setProgress(progress);
            }
         }
      });

      theDownload.execute();
   }

}

class AtomFrame extends JFrame {

   // ********* should be private!
   private JProgressBar progressBar;

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 4010489530693307355L;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      AtomFrame testFrame = new AtomFrame();
      testFrame.start();
   }

   public void setProgress(int progress) {
      progressBar.setValue(progress);
   }

   public AtomFrame() {
      initializeComponents();
   }

   public void initializeComponents() {
      this.setSize(400, 400);
      this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      this.setTitle("Atom Launcher");
      this.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 5));

      progressBar = new JProgressBar();
      this.add(progressBar);

      // this.pack();
   }

   public void start() {
      this.setVisible(true);
   }

   public void close() {
      this.dispose();
   }
}

class Download extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {
   private static final long SLEEP_TIME = 300;
   private Random random = new Random();

   @Override
   protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
      int myProgress = 0;
      while (myProgress < 100) {
         myProgress += random.nextInt(10);
         setProgress(myProgress);
         try {
            Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
      }
      return null;
   }
}
```

Comment: Totally didn't expect the example. You rock! Thanks for the wealth of knowledge.